# What user permissions are needed to reflect an Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a read-only user for an Oracle 11g Database that will be used by SQLAlchemy to query the database.
I was using an existing DBA user with SQLAlchemy and wasn't having any problems, but now with the new user, I am unable to reflect database tables.

```
Could not reflect: requested table(s) not available in Engine
```

Note that I can SELECT the tables, just not reflect them.
I am wondering what kind of permissions I need to give to the new user for it to able to reflect through SQLALchemy.

I tried copying all roles from the existing DBA to the new user, but still get the same error

I even tried some advanced roles that weren't used before (I plan on deleting and adding the user correctly again later.
DBACONSULTA is the new user I am creating.

```
GRANT DBA TO DBACONSULTA
GRANT EXECUTE ANY EVALUATION CONTEXT TO DBACONSULTA
GRANT ANALYZE ANY TO DBACONSULTA
GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO DBACONSULTA
GRANT EXECUTE ANY PROGRAM TO DBACONSULTA
```

With Python I use the following code:

```
engine=create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://...')
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine, only=['tablename'])
```

Get the error:

```
Could not reflect: requested table(s) not available in Engine
```

I want to be able to reflect tables, without using the Declarative form from SQLAlchemy

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By default, Oracle will store the object names (columns, tables, etc) in upper-case. Have you tried `'TABLENAME'` rather than `'tablename'`?

Comment: Yes I did.
I also believe SQLAlchemy does the uppercasing by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the answers.

Two things that are important:

- the table name had to be in lowercase (didn't work using uppercase)
- the schema was not defined (turn out it was working because the user I was using was the owner of the schema of the tables)

So, when i declare the schema and use lowercase for the tablename the reflection works.